# Как вывести сумму всех значений ячейки mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть запрос:

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT sum(price) FROM items"); 
$sum=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo ($sum);
```

Но он выводит ARRAY. Каким образом нужно вывести сумму чисел в ячейке?

Comment: внезапно, но `echo ($sum['sum(price)'])`

Comment: ох блин, ахахаха, спасибо

Comment: можно и mysqli_fetch_assoc .... в запросе делать alias: `SELECT sum(price) as price` и доставать как $sum['price']

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT sum(price) FROM items"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $row[0];
```

[Справочник](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @Mcile, и чем же этот ответ неправилен?

Comment: @Mcile, если вы не знаете как работает `mysqli_fetch_array()`, то не надо лезть со своими голословными утверждениями! Идите по ссылке и читайте `Выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба`

Answer (score -1):

Ну как костыльный вариант, думаю сойдет так:

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT sum(price) sum_price FROM items")); 
echo $res['sum_price'];
```

Comment: Спасибо, напомнили мне о том, какие я глупые вопросы задавал.